# solve a set in 'algerba of sets' way.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

1. two question, need to solve each in 'algebra of sets' way

   $$(A \cup B) - (C \cap  D) = (A - C) \cup (A - D)
       \cup (B - C) \cup (B - D)$$

   $$(A \cup B) \cap  (C \cap  D)^\complement = (A
       \cap  C^\complement) \cup (A \cap  D^\complement)
       \cup (B \cap  C^\complement) \cup (B \cap 
       D^\complement)$$ becuase I know that for two sets, $A - B = A \cap B'$

   $$(A \cup B) \cap  (C \cap  D)^\complement = A \cap 
       (C^\complement \cup D^\complement) \cup B \cap 
       (C^\complement \cup D^\complement)$$ distribute the right
   side of the equation

   $$(A \cup B) \cap  (C^\complement \cup D^\complement)
       = A \cap  (C^\complement \cup D^\complement) \cup B \cap  (C^\complement \cup D^\complement)$$ apply de
   morgan on the left side

   $$(A \cap  C^\complement) \cup (A \cap  D^\complement)
       \cup (B \cap  C^\complement) \cup (B \cap 
       D^\complement) = A \cap  (C^\complement \cup
       D^\complement) \cup B \cap  (C^\complement \cup
       D^\complement)$$ I don't know if it's legal? just how I see it, any
   other way to distribute here?

   $$A \cap  (C^\complement \cup D^\complement) \cup B
       \cap  (C^\complement \cup D^\complement) = A \cap 
       (C^\complement \cup D^\complement) \cup B \cap 
       (C^\complement \cup D^\complement)$$ distribute the left side
2. $A \oplus B = A^\complement \oplus B^\complement$

   $$(A - B) \cup (B - A) = (A - B)^\complement \cup (B -
       A)^\complement$$ *i know the left side of the equation is legal for
   me to do, but is the right side also?*

   $$(A \cap  B^\complement) \cup (B \cap  A^\complement)
       = (A \cap  B^\complement)^\complement  \cup (B \cap  A^\complement)^\complement$$ *again I know that for 2 sets $A-B = A
       \cap B'$. is the right side of the equation legal for me to do?*

   can someone tell me how do I go from here?

Answer (score 1):

In the first problem, note that when you get to:

$$\begin{align} ...&= A \cap  (C^\complement \cup D^\complement) \cup B \cap  (C^\complement \cup D^\complement)\\ \\ & = (A \cap  C^\complement) \cup (A \cap  D^\complement)
    \cup (B \cap  C^\complement) \cup (B \cap 
    D^\complement)\end{align}\tag{1}$$
(You mention De Morgan's when moving from the left to the right side of the equation, but this equation holds by applying the distributive law.)

Note that you are virtually done. (All the work you do after obtaining $(1)$ is merely circular, taking you back to where you started.)

Now from $(1)$, you need only apply the definition you suggested at the start: $$P - Q = P\cap Q^\complement$$

This gives you, as desired: $$(A \cap  C^\complement) \cup (A \cap  D^\complement)
    \cup (B \cap  C^\complement) \cup (B \cap 
    D^\complement) = (A - C) \cup (A - D) \cup (B-C) \cup (B - D)$$

---

$(2)$ From the start, the following is NOT valid: $$(A - B) \cup (B - A) = (A - B)^\complement \cup (B -
    A)^\complement$$

Rather, let's start off with what you know to be equivalent:

$$\begin{align} A \oplus B & = (A - B)\cup (B - A) \\ \\&= (A\cap B^\complement) \cup (B\cap A^\complement)\\ \\ & = \ldots\end{align}$$

Comment: can you pleae explain how you got from A⊕B=A∁⊕B∁ to (A−B)∪(B−A)=(A∩B∁)∪(B∩A∁)

Comment: I was simply expanding on the left hand side: $A\oplus B$...You expand on the left side to try to obtain the right side $A^\complement \oplus B^\complement$. The objective is to *show* the left side equals the left side, and to do this you cannot *assume* the left hand side is equal to the right hand side.

Comment: Can you please tell me why what I did was not valid? and I still don't understand what you did, I know that A⊕B=(A∩B∁)∪(B∩A∁). but what about the right side of the equation A∁⊕B∁? sorry for my lack of understanding, I signed up for discrete math at the university and it's my first time seeing math after years, and thank you.

Comment: I did not complete the process in $(2)$. More steps are needed to *arrive at* the right-hand side $A^\complement \oplus B^\complement$. The objective is to try to work with one side of the equation to obtain the right-hand side.

Comment: can I go (A∩B∁)∪(B∩A∁) = A∪(B∩A∁)∩B∁∪(B∩A∁)?

Comment: Yes, indeed you can!